# Haskell type variable not resolving

Tags: haskell

I have the following snippet of code

```
class LatticeElement a where
    next :: a -> a -- next element     

class (Ord a, LatticeElement a) => LatticeDate a where
    prev :: a -> a -- prev date

data LatticeSlice d v = forall d v. (LatticeDate d, LatticeElement v) => LatticeSlice{date :: d, slice :: v}

map :: (v -> w) -> LatticeSlice d v -> LatticeSlice d w
map f LatticeSlice{date = d, slice = sl} = LatticeSlice{date = d, slice = f sl}
```

Which causes a compilation error. Now, as far as I understand the code, first I set up `LatticeElement` as a typeclass, then `LatticeDate` as a specialisation of the `LatticeElement` typecleass, requiring that the type `d` is an instance of `Ord`.

Now I create `LatticeSlice`, with a declaration that I read something like "`LatticeSlice` is a data type on types `d` and `v`, constrained to exist only for all types `d` instantiating `LatticeDate` and `v` instantiating `LatticeElement`"

The error comes in the instantiation of `map`:

```
src/Lattice.hs:9:77: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘v’ with actual type ‘v1’
      ‘v1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          LatticeSlice :: forall d1 v1 d2 v2.
                          (LatticeDate d2, LatticeElement v2) =>
                          d2 -> v2 -> LatticeSlice d1 v1,
        in an equation for ‘map’
        at src/Lattice.hs:9:7-40
      ‘v’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          Lattice.map :: forall v w d.
                         (v -> w) -> LatticeSlice d v -> LatticeSlice d w
        at src/Lattice.hs:8:1-55
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘sl’
      In the ‘slice’ field of a record
      In the expression: LatticeSlice {date = d, slice = f sl}
    • Relevant bindings include
        sl :: v1 (bound at src/Lattice.hs:9:38)
        f :: v -> w (bound at src/Lattice.hs:9:5)
        map :: (v -> w) -> LatticeSlice d v -> LatticeSlice d w
          (bound at src/Lattice.hs:9:1)
```

I think that the compiler is telling me that it isn't resolving the `v` in `(v -> w)` to be the same type as the `v` in `LatticeSlice d v`. But I don't know why it is doing this, or more to the point, what to do about it!

Comment: Why do you use `forall`?

Comment: The for all probably isn't doing what you think it is.  A GADT might simplify things.

Answer (score 3):

First of all the `forall d v.` shadows the arguments of `LatticeSlice`.

```
                  d1           d2                d2                                           d2
                  |            |                 |                                            |
                  v            v                 v                                            v
data LatticeSlice d v = forall d v. (LatticeDate d, LatticeElement v) => LatticeSlice{date :: d, slice :: v}
                    ^            ^                                 ^                                      ^
                    |            |                                 |                                      |
                    v1           v2                                v2                                     v2
```

The type of `LatticeSlice` demonstrates this

```
>> :set -fprint-explicit-foralls
>> :t +v LatticeSlice
LatticeSlice
  :: forall d1 v1 d2 v2.
     (LatticeDate d2, LatticeElement v2) =>
     d2 -> v2 -> LatticeSlice d1 v1
```

The argument types of value constructor has `d2` and `v2` has nothing to do with the arguments of the type constructor `d1` and `v1`:

```
instance LatticeDate    ()
instance LatticeElement ()

ls :: LatticeSlice d v
ls = LatticeSlice () ()
```

If you remove the `forall` quantifiers your datatype is carrying around the constraint, in this case I recommend againt it! It is equivalent to this GADT:

```
data LatticeSlice d v where
  LatticeSlice :: (LatticeDate d, LatticeElement v) => {date :: d, slice :: v} -> LatticeSlice d v
```

The constraint encumbers your definitions, `map` can not be parametric in the `w` argument. Just because `v` is a `LatticeElement` does not mean `w` is. Therefore we must witness that `f sl :: w` is a `LatticeElement w`:

```hs
map :: LatticeElement w => (v -> w) -> LatticeSlice d v -> LatticeSlice d w
map f LatticeSlice{date = d, slice = sl} = LatticeSlice{date = d, slice = f sl}
```

This makes it incompatible with the basic infrastructure like `Functor` (`Applicative`, `Monad`..) and `Bifunctor` (`Biapplicative`, ..).

This is the best version, if you need lattice constraints you add them to the functions that operate on `LatticeSlice`

```
data LatticeSlice d v = LatticeSlice {date :: d, slice :: v}
  deriving stock Functor

instance Bifunctor LatticeSlice where
  bimap :: (d -> d') -> (s -> s') -> (LatticeSlice d s -> LatticeSlice d' s')
  bimap f g as = bipure f g <<*>> as

instance Biapplicative LatticeSlice where
  bipure :: d -> s -> LatticeSlice d s
  bipure = LatticeSlice

  biliftA2 :: (d1 -> d2 -> d3)
           -> (s1 -> s2 -> s3)
           -> (LatticeSlice d1 s1 -> LatticeSlice d2 s2 -> LatticeSlice d3 s3)
  biliftA2 (·) (×) (LatticeSlice d1 s1) (LatticeSlice d2 s2) =
    LatticeSlice (d1 · d2) (s1 × s2)
```

Watch Edward Kmett's [Type Classes vs. the World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIZxTQP1ifo) for more information.